# Generating new Polyline on google maps for each "date" value from mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

**Edit:**
I'm trying over the last couple of weeks to solve my problem. As I'm a True Beginner I'm learning the Code during the work Progress... I will try to clarify my question which hopefully show me the answer.

As i was asking before : I'm developing a web App based on Google maps API 3. A GPS-Logger is feeding a table on Mysql server with those values: id, latitude, longitude, date, time, userid. I want to create multiple unique Polylines. For each **date group** a new Polyline.

As I was saying, I've made some progress but I'm not quite sure that I'm on the right track.

Now I'm not sure what I'm getting it ether few Polylines that are connected making them into a big Polyline or Few Polylines on top of each others...
Another problem ist that with this code I can't seem to show the first "date-group Polyline".

I've Posted the Newer code Below the Original one and a >>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dphCu/2/)**<< link (although I didn't managed to get jsfiddle working on my side).

I assuming that this is no longer a Google-Maps question but I would be thankful if someone can help me to solve and understand it.

This is the code part I've posted before:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("output-xml.php", function(data) 
  {
    var points=[];
    var markerbgn=[];
    var markerend=[];
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
    {
      var date = markers[i].getAttribute("date");
      var time = markers[i].getAttribute("time");
      var timebgn = markers[0].getAttribute("time");
      var timeend = markers[markers.length-1].getAttribute("time");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("usid");

          points[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

      var html1 = "<b>" + date + "</b> <br/>" + timebgn + "</b> <br/>" + "Start Point";
      var html2 = "<b>" + date + "</b> <br/>" + timeend + "</b> <br/>" + "End Point";
      var content2 = "<b>" + "User: " + type + "</b> <br/>" + date + "</b> <br/>" + "User Route";

    var encoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(points);         
    console.log(encoded_path);

    }

    var decoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_path);

    // Polyline
    var polyOptions = {
      path: decoded_path,
      map: map,
      clickable: true,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    }

    //line text
    var info = decoded_path;

    // Polyline
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    polyline.setMap(map);
    createInfoWindow(polyline, map, infoWindow, content2);
```

This is the Newer Code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
downloadUrl("output-xml.php", function(data) {
    var markerbgn=[];
    var markerend=[];
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var routeNum = [];
    var mPoints =[]; 

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length-1; i++) {

        var date = markers[i].getAttribute("date").split("-").join("");
        var dateAdv = markers[i+1].getAttribute("date").split("-").join("");
        var datePrv = [];
        var dateEnd = markers[markers.length-1].getAttribute("date").split("-").join("");
        var time = markers[i].getAttribute("time");
        var timebgn = markers[0].getAttribute("time");
        var timeend = markers[markers.length-1].getAttribute("time");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("usid");
        var routesCng=[];
        var points=[];

        if (dateAdv != date){
            if (!routesCng) routesCng=[];
            routesCng = i;
            routeNum++;

            for (var k = 0; k < markers.length; k++) {  
                points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[k].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[k].getAttribute("lng"))));
            }
                        setPoints();
                        setPolyline();      
        }
        //alert([datePrv,time,dateAdv]); //**********************************
        var html1 = "<b>" + date + "</b> <br/>" + timebgn + "</b> <br/>" + "Start Point";
        var html2 = "<b>" + date + "</b> <br/>" + timeend + "</b> <br/>" + "End Point";
        var content2 = "<b>" + type + "</b> <br/>" + dateAdv + "</b> <br/>" + "User Route";
    }       
    function setPoints() {
        mPoints = points.splice([routesCng]);
            //alert([date,routesCng,dateAdv,routeNum]);

    }

    function setPolyline() {
        alert([date,routesCng,dateAdv,routeNum,mPoints]);
        var encoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(mPoints);
            console.log(encoded_path);
        var decoded_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_path);
        var polyOptions = {
                path: decoded_path,
                map: map,
                clickable: true,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            }
        // Polyline
        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);

        //line text
        var info = decoded_path;
        polyline.setMap(map);

        createInfoWindow(polyline, map, infoWindow, content2);

        if(decoded_path.length!=0){  
            markerbgn = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: decoded_path[0],
                draggable: false,
                visible: true
            });
        markerend = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: decoded_path[decoded_path.length-1],
            draggable: false,
            visible: true
            });
        bindInfoWindow(markerbgn, map, infoWindow, html1);
        bindInfoWindow(markerend, map, infoWindow, html2);
        }
    }   
});
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need multiple `decoded_path`. Looks like you've got only one.

Comment: That was the part i was straggling with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this in the client, but one way to do it would be to create an array of points for each date:

```
if (!points[date]) points[date] = [];
points[date].push(new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))));
```

then create your unique polylines from each of those arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, this solution seemed for me the right way to go. Somehow i was unable to populate the Polyline. It seems that my points[date] array is empty and i cant figure out why.

Comment: If you provide a link to your map that exhibits the problem (or a jsfiddle), then someone might be able to help.

Comment: The code is running under local server and I have no experience with jsfiddle. If it would help i can post the whole code. BTY while i was testing the date value in the array with: `var dateBgn = markers[0].getAttribute("date"); if (dateBgn == date)
      { 
       points[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))); 
      }`  I was manage to popolate the first part of the Polyline (route).

Comment: Posting the whole page is better than nothing, someone might be able to help.  The advantage of a link or jsfiddle is it saves the time of the people that are trying to help by preventing copy/paste errors and issues, and often in simplifying the problem to post it on jsfiddle you find the problem.

Comment: I've Posted the code in question on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0uEMy21f). I will try to Post it also on jsfiddle after I'll isolate the mysql part.